# Don't cut off foldername in genericList

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0, acl, generic-list

I have some code which writes the permissions of a specific user on a folder with all subfolders into a generic list. Later in the code, I will print this list. However, if the Directory is too large (4+ Folders, the name gets cut off. I need to write down the whole directory name and not just a shortened version. Is there some kind of a parameter I can use?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$User = "Testumgebung\cbruehwiler"
$UserOhneDomain = $User -creplace '^[^\\]*\\', ''
$Path = "\\ESX-SHARE\File Transfer"

$List = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserOhneDomain 
$From = $User

$GroupArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
$GroupArrayList.Add($Group.Name) | Out-Null 
} 

$OutputFields = @(
    @{name="Item" ;       expression={$_.Path.split(':',3)[-1]}}
    @{name="Rights" ;     expression={$Right.FileSystemRights}}
    @{name="AccessType" ; expression={$Right.AccessControlType}}
    @{name="From" ;       expression={$From}}
) 

$FileSystemObjects = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName}

foreach ($Item in $FileSystemObjects) {
    foreach ($Right in $Item.Access) {
        if ($Right.IdentityReference -eq $User -And ($Right.IsInherited -eq $false))
        {
            $From = $User
            $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
        }
        foreach ($GroupArrayItem in $GroupArrayList){
            if ($Right.IdentityReference -eq ("TESTUMGEBUNG\" + $GroupArrayItem) -And ($Right.IsInherited -eq $false)) 
            {
                $From = $GroupArrayItem
                $List.Add(($Item | Select-Object $OutputFields))
            }
        }
    }   
}

$List | Out-File C:\Users\cbruehwiler\Desktop\PermissionCheck.csv
$DateTime = Get-Date
$DateTime >> C:\Users\cbruehwiler\Desktop\PermissionCheck.csv
```

This is how the result looks.

```
Item                                                                   Rights                                    AccessType From             

----                                                                   ------                                    ---------- ----                                          
\\ESX-SHARE\File Transfer\TestFolder\Sub_Te...                         FullControl                                    Allow Testumgebung\cbruehwiler
```

However I would like to have it like this

```
\\ESX-SHARE\File Transfer\TestFolder\Sub_TestFolder\Sub_Sub_TestFolder
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like some of your code is missing...

Comment: It Should not be that important. I guess it's a syntax issue or maybe it's an issue from powershell.

Comment: It is quite important - if this is what you see when the objects are rendered in your console, that's expected - the strings are not "cut off", but the formatting subsystem in PowerShell truncates them to make room on the screen. If you export the data to a text file or a csv you'll likely find that your strings are perfectly intact

Comment: Again, _how_ you do it might be important, so please update your post with the exact steps and commands you run in order to get the result your describing

Comment: Alright thanks. Did not know that.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely want to switch to `$List | Export-Csv PermissionCheck.csv` instead of `Out-File` if you want a csv

Comment: It's unbelievable that this fixed the problem. Is there a way how I can export it to a .txt too?

Comment: Sure, but - what would your txt file to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting to a CSV file with `Out-File`. That's incorrect; you need `Export-Csv`. You'll want to drop the date output in your last line too, if you want a legal CSV document. (You can run `Get-Item MyFile.csv | Format-Table Name, CreationTime` to get that info later; the filesystem gives you some date information for free.)

This in itself represents a complete solution. Your output won't be truncated. But I'd like to explain the distinction, if I may.

Powershell has some default actions that are getting hooked in your code snippet. `Out-File` takes string content but you are passing objects, so PS is going to use its default formatter. When the first item down the pipeline has 4 or fewer visible properties, that will be `Format-Table`, otherwise `Format-List`.

`Format-Table` has a `-Wrap` switch which causes overflowing content to wrap instead of truncate. Sometimes, using `-AutoSize` is also sufficient to adjust the column widths, but this will only get you so far when the problem is truncation. `Format-List` will always wrap.

If all you want is that one property and you can afford to lose the column header, try piping to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Item`.

As I hope is now clear, these formatting commands are flattening structured data into text, albeit formatted text. This will always give you a loss of fidelity and also make it harder to do any further manipulation on the data. If you use `Export-Csv` instead, you can later run `Import-Csv` to get the data back as structured output. Plus, you can open in Excel, etc.

A word of warning: `Export-Csv` doesn't handle quotemarks well. If that becomes an issue, try `Export-CliXml`, which uses a PS-specific dialect of XML, and provides the highest fidelity you can get (unless you're willing to put in a LOT of work!) Naturally, the import counterpart of that command is `Import-CliXml`.

One last tip for `Export-Csv`: often you do not want the header information, so use it with the `-NoTypeInformation` switch.